# Insert/Update Triggers

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have 2 triggers (Insert and Update)

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_InsertTrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        Update a previous record if found
    END //

CREATE TRIGGER my_UpdateTrigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        .....
    END //
```

According to my understanding triggers cannot be fire programmatically/manually, it only fires when an insert/update/delete happens on that table.

So my question is in the case mentioned above, will the insert trigger(my_InsertTrigger) invoke the update trigger (my_UpdateTrigger)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have tagged the question "sql-server" and yet the syntax suggests MySQL (or perhaps another database).  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Why don't just test it yourself?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I removed the tags sql and sql-server

Comment: So which DBMS _are_ you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Fully agree with Rahul. You will also memorize it much better, if you just try it. And it saves us some work.

Comment: But the syntax is **completely** wrong for SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have not written the syntax here. This is just the pseudo code.

Comment: If you want an answer concerning triggers in SQL Server you should write the triggers in T-SQL. SQL Server for example does not have "row level" triggers. So the pseudo-code starts with a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I changed the trigger syntax to SQL Server (with just inserting one row) one trigger that causes an update on a table will kick off the update trigger on that table (if it exists).

I have seen this on audit tables and two things can, and will, happen:

1) Performance will suffer.

2) If the audit triggers start kicking each other off (by having cross trggers) you can run out of stack space (The triggers can nest 32 levels down).